# How can i get the PIN2 number?

Tags: android

If user want to open the "Fixed dialing number" feature，he must input the PIN2 of SIM card. So the phone must save the the PIN2 of SIM card，then it must to determine whether the PIN2 correct. I want to ask are there some APIs to get the PIN2 number on Android? or the telephone module use other solution to get PIN2.

Comment: you are asking for security hole. PINs are processed/verified on SIM card and it is security requirement that this data are not available outside of SIM card.

Comment: yes, it looks like that the phone send a command to modem. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean PIN number like on a Blackberry, there isn't one.
Android phone has IMEI (International Mobile Station Equipment Identity) number only

Answer (score 0):

Well it is, in most cases, impossible to get phone number because this information is not stored on device, I believe the same case is with PIN numbers, all data is stored at carrier database.

Answer (score 0):

I read this a elsewhere and it worked.   I have had the same issue on setting up my Son's FDN. 5678 is PIN2.

I read elsewhere.... Pin1 is always 1234 and pin 2 is always 5678. Found it on the web. Worked for me.

And it worked for me.. hope it works for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).